# Filtro com Data e Hora especifica das ultimas 24h

Tags: sql, sql-server, query, datetime, data

Estou com a seguinte situação:

- Preciso exibir todas as ordens de serviços lançadas a partir das 07h da manhã do dia anterior, até as 07h da manhã do dia atual. Consigo fazer isso quando quero retornar as ordens de serviços lançadas nas ultimas 24h a partir do horário atual, porem como disse antes, preciso que seja filtrado num horário especifico.

```
SELECT SERIE, NUMERO, DATA
FROM ORDENS
WHERE 
DATA >= Convert(varchar(10), GETDATE() - 1, 120) AND
DATA < = Convert(varchar(10), GETDATE() - 1, 120) AND
```

Comment: Se você alterar para isso funciona? `DATA >= '2022-04-12 07:00:00'   AND
DATA <=  '2022-04-13 07:00:00'`. Se funciona é só tratar os dados informados no `where`

Comment: Funciona, mas não serve para o que preciso, pois esta visualização tem que ser gerada de forma automática e diariamente. A intenção é não ter interferência de usuário para alterar esta data todos os dias.

Comment: Exatamente isso, agora é só adaptar seu código para que seja montado isso. A hora é fixa, a sua única variante é a data, sendo que é a data atual -1. Dá uma olhada na [documentação da MS sobre GetDate](https://docs.microsoft.com/fr-ca/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Obrigado Leandro, a documentação serviu muito para meus estudos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue uma sugestão para testes utilizando a função SmallDateTimeFromParts para obter a data atual as 7:00 e depois a função DateAdd para obter o dia anterior as 7:00:

```
declare @DataHoraFim as datetime2 = 
    smalldatetimefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), day(getdate()), 7, 0);
declare @DataHoraIni as datetime2 = 
    dateadd(day, -1, @DataHoraFim);

SELECT SERIE, NUMERO, DATA
FROM ORDENS
WHERE DATA BETWEEN @DataHoraIni and @DataHoraFim
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente.